# Is there any way to get Bangla Fonts properly in VS Code Console?

Tags: visual-studio-code, speech-recognition

I am trying to build a Bangla speech recognizing bot using python (Google Speech recognition) on VSCode. The program is working 
fine but the font is not coming properly.

[image]

Comment: what shell is this? are you on windows? if so, what codepage is the console using? (you can check with the chcp.com command). what is it supposed to look like?

Comment: No, I couldn't solve it.